1D Lattice with site dependent magnetic field
An external magnetic field is on a 1D lattice with N sites where each site has a magnetic moment, which can rotate freely. The magnetic field at the $j^{th}$ site is,
$$\mathbf{B}_j = B_0 \cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) \hat{z} + B_0 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) \hat{x}.$$ There is no interaction between the magnetic moments.
I need to find the partition function for this system. I have proceeded by trying to evaluate the partition function at the $j^{th} site first$,
\begin{alignat}{1}
Z & = \prod_j \int d\Omega_j \, e^{-\beta H_j} \\
  & = \prod_j \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi_j \int_0^\pi \sin\theta_j \ d\theta_j \ e^{-\beta H_j}  \\
  & = \prod_j \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi_j \int_0^\pi \sin\theta_j \ d\theta_j \ e^{\beta m B_0 \left[ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) \cos\theta_j + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) \sin\theta_j \cos\phi_j \right]} 
\end{alignat}
where:
\begin{alignat}{1}
d\Omega_j & = \sin\theta_j \ d\theta_j \ d\phi_j, \\
H_j & = -B_0 \left[ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) m_z + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right) m_x \right]
\end{alignat}
I am unable to integrate the partition function at the $j^{th}$ site in the above form, so one way in which I could proceed was orienting the z-axis at each site along the magnetic field at that site. This leads to the same result for the partition function if we had a uniform magnetic field like $\mathbf{B}= B_{o}\hat{z}$ . If this is the correct method, how do I interpret this result?

I would say the result is just a statement about the structure of the phase/configuration space, which is spherical with no preferred direction(s) in the case of a magnetic moment.
The partition function $Z$ is a function of $\beta$ and $\vec{B}$:
$$Z(\beta, \vec{B}) = \int \mathrm{d}\vec{s} e^{\beta \vec{B}\cdot\vec{s}},$$
where $\vec{s}$ takes all allowed values in the configuration space. The computation indicates that $Z$ does not depend on the direction of $\vec{B}$. In other words, if one maps $\vec{B}$ to a rotated vector $\vec{B'}$, one can find a change of integration variable $\vec{s'}$ that restores the original expression for $Z$.
What does this mean? Imagine instead that the moments could only be aligned along $\pm \hat{z}$. Here, the direction of $\vec{B}$ clearly matters when finding $Z_j$ $-$ there is no reparametrization of the configuration space that maintains the expression.
$$Z_j = 2\cosh\left(\beta B_0 \cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{N}\right)\right).$$
This indicates that the structure of the configuration space is important. For a magnetic moment which is unrestricted in its orientation, the sum over allowed states (the entire spherical shell) in $Z$ ensures that $\vec{B}$'s direction doesn't matter.
It might also be helpful to look at the answers to these questions, which try to give a physical meaning to the partition function.

Can you please delete this answer? I want to delete this question due to some personal reasons. I am very sorry about it. I had forgotten about the question as I had posted it a while back. Thank you.

Oh, um... I'm not sure what the site policy on this is, but I think you can delete the question anyway. If that isn't possible, let me know, and I'll delete the answer.
